# Create a shortcode to use in visual editor

Tags: shortcode

I'm using Visual composer and i can't use php code inside boxes but i can use shortcodes.
I know i must use function inside my functions.php file

I need only a example/help for one and i will contruct the rest of shortcodes.

```
<div class="header-image"><?php 

$image = get_field('imagen_superior');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?></div>
```

Comment: I would note that if we gave you what you're asking for literally, rather than as a shortcode, e.g. a `[php]` shortcode, the answer would be a ***massive*** security hole of unprecedented proportions, the kind which will probably be picked up automatically by security tools and blocked, the sort that some hosts would automatically suspend your account for. In a lot of agencies, such code would mean instant dismissal. Such is the badness of functions such as `eval`

Comment: then... i can't insert custom fields inside visual composer??

Comment: Not by copy pasting PHP into an editable field in your UI, via shortcodes, yes, or via the visual composer API ( you'll need to speak with someone familiar with visual composer, VC specific support is off-topic here )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, make a shortcode:

```
function my_image() {

        $image = get_field('imagen_superior');
        if( !empty($image) ) {

                echo '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" />';

        }

}

function my_shortcode( $attr ) {

                return '<div class="header-image">' . my_image() . '</div>';    

}

add_shortcode( 'my-shortcode', 'my_shortcode' );
```

and then place `[my-shortcode]` in the visual composer.

Comment: thanks samuel, i know do that, the problem is insert php in the content. Can you help me with this please? If i see one, i can do others :) I tried but i have problems with ' '' <?php etc...

Comment: Sure. let me edit my answer then :)

Comment: I have edited it, please let me know if it works.

Comment: sorry but don't show nothing. and i'm sure that code works because in php file works... And i know shortcodes works on visual composer text box because in other website works... must be something wrong in code... maybe is the <?php inside other <?php

Comment: Why use ?> at beginning? and the last <?php

Comment: i think must use echo'' or similar... not close php at begin and php opening at the end... ??

Comment: maybe some error writting @samuel ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I ve been working on it. I don't know if your function returns something.. but in light of your recent comments, I edited the code and maybe you should try this : http://pastebin.com/BRcznhHZ then let me know how it goes.

Comment: thanks for try it @samuel but don't show nothing :( you can see it here http://orahuesca.com/pruebamaqueta/prueba/ inside red box <div class="vc_col-sm-4 wpb_column vc_column_container ">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
   
  </div> 
 </div>

Comment: Sorry to hear about that. well, the shortcode works, and only function `my_image()` doesn't return anything. tell me more about `$image = get_field('imagen_superior');` how do you use it to retrieve data ? in this case, is it empty ? you can test it giving a default image source if empty or using `var_dump()`

Comment: here this code (in php file) is working http://orahuesca.com/pruebamaqueta/funcionamiento/ (top photo). this custom field is created with Advanced Custom Fields ACF @samuel

Comment: Are you saying the code in the pastebin works in that page you linked ? sorry but I am kinda new to PHP, how would the function retrieve the image url if there was no image set in the ACF ? `if( !empty($image) ) { echo '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" />';}`

try out a default URL perhaps..

Comment: everything is my fault. i don't upload image in page :( really really thanks!!!!!! please, change code in answer and vote you up! thanks again @samuel

Comment: HAHA! dude, I was waiting to hear that, good for us both.
updating the answer . Enjoy ^^
You're welcome !!